# Java Sockets - Running the same client multiple times in parallel.

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, parallel-processing, client-server

(Disclaimer that some of this code will be similar to online tutorials)

---

I think I've made it so that my server can handle multiple requests at once using threads, but I'm not entirely sure. And on top of that I don't know how I would actually *send* multiple requests at once.

My goal is to run my client code multiple times in parallel to see what happens if multiple clients connect to the server at the same time.

Client code (in separate project package):

```
        Client clientSocket = new Client(9990,"localhost");
        Socket socket = new Socket(clientSocket.host,clientSocket.portNumber);
        clientSocket.performTask(socket);
```

("performTask(socket)" sends data to the server to perform a task)

Server code (separate project package from client code):

```
    Server server = new Server(9990);
    int clientNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(server.portNumber);
    try { 
        while (true) {
            new ServerHandler(socket.accept(),clientNumber).go();
            clientNumber++;
        }
    }
    finally {
        socket.close();
        }
}
```

ServerHandler class (same project package as server code):

```
public class ServerHandler extends Thread {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static int clientNumber;

    public ServerHandler(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        ServerHandler.socket = socket;
        ServerHandler.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    }

    public void go() {
        while(true) {
        try {
            //do calculation, do server tasks, etc.
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

So when the client connects to the server, the server implements the ServerHandler class to do the necessary calculations: the idea in doing that was so that multiple clients could connect all at the same time.

So my question is then in two parts:

(1) Have I set up my programs to allow for multi-threading, or have I made a mistake somewhere along the way? *(e.g. someone told me I needed to use "Runnable" somewhere to use multi-threading, and I notice I haven't)*

(2) After fixing my code to allow for multi-threading, how would I actually use it to let me run my client code in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

Ok for starters, your `ServerHandler` extends the `Thread` class. Therefore to make it run as a seperate thread, always invoke by calling the `start()` method. You are calling you custom `go` method which will make the `ServerHandler` execute in the same thread as your infinite while loop. So it should be something like this  `ServerHandler(socket.accept(),clientNumber).start()`. Also it is always better to implement Runnable because java does not support multiple inheritance via the "extends" concept. Therefore in the future if your ServerHandler needs to actually extend a custom class, it wont be able to since it already extends the `Thread` class. Its better to implement interfaces since there is no limit as to how many you can implement.

Hence implementing the Runnable interface is a good design choice. You can run your client code in parallel by making the client into a threaded model. Here is one such example of multiple client sockets connecting to the server in parallel

Server Code

```
public class WebServer {
    static int hitCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777, 10000);
        while (true) {
            Socket defaultSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ServerSlave(defaultSocket)).start();
            System.out.println("Size is :" + hitCount);
        }

    }
}

class ServerSlave implements Runnable {
    Socket clientSocket;

    public ServerSlave(Socket socket) {
        clientSocket = socket;
        WebServer.hitCount++;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
            outputStream.writeUTF("Thank you for contacting the web server");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code :

```
public class Client {
    static int excepCount=0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Worker("" + i)).start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println( Client.excepCount);
    }
}


class Worker implements Runnable {
    String clientName;

    public Worker(String name) {
        clientName = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Process started for : " + clientName);
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7777);
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeUTF("Hello socket. Client number " + clientName + "here");
            InputStream inFromServer = socket.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in =
                    new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readUTF());
            System.out.println("Closing socket");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Client.excepCount++;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,

So the way for me to generate multiple simultaneous requests from the client is to have a 2nd class in the Client project as well similar to the 2nd class I have in my server project?

Comment: You can either do that or you can have the client class itself implement Runnable and then have a loop in the main method and generate a new Thread object and pass it an instance of your client and invoke start on it. :)

Comment: yes! I did that, and used a loop from i=0 to 1, and it worked. 

But when I did 2 or any higher than that, it didn't work. It seemed to just start running forever. 

I'm not quite sure what the issue there is :(

Comment: I'm reading values onto the server side and if I have more than 1 client it just stops halfway through (I read in with a for loop, and with 2 clients it only does half the iterations and then stops and just goes to an infinite loop).

Comment: I have an EOF exception after reading the input from the 1st thread

Comment: If possible, can you post the code that you are trying with ??

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading .
 You have to rename method to "run"/ and call that method using "start".Please change Server side  code to

```
try { 
        while (true) {
            new ServerHandler(socket.accept(),clientNumber).start();
            clientNumber++;
        }
    }
    finally {
        socket.close();
        }
```

and client side

```
public class ServerHandler extends Thread {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static int clientNumber;

    public ServerHandler(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        ServerHandler.socket = socket;
        ServerHandler.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
        try {
            //do calculation, do server tasks, etc.
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: I fixed the run() vs start(), but my client side is in a different project package than my ServerHandler class.

After changing run() and start(), how would I now generate simultaneous requests from my client?

Comment: If you are not able to run your client project from separate computer, what You can do is running your client side project multiple times from your machine. Most of the IDE support that . Which IDE you are using ?